# GET request working through Postman but the browser tells me GET request cannot have body

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, fetch

I'm simply trying to send some urlencoded parameters via a GET request using `fetch`. I'm just trying to print the parameters using Express at the moment, like so:

```
app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
    return;
});
```

This works just fine in Postman using a GET request and x-www-form-urlencoded key-value pairs. The webserver will print all the key-value pairs just fine.

But when I try and use `fetch` to do the exact same thing I get nothing but problems. I've tried two different methods:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api?user=test&password=123`, {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
});
```

The request **does** go through using this method, but the webserver only prints `{}` - an empty object.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("user", "test");
urlencoded.append("password", "123");

var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: urlencoded,
};

fetch("localhost:3000/api", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

The request **does not** go through using this method, and the browser gives me the error `TypeError: Window.fetch: HEAD or GET Request cannot have a body.`
This code was generated using the request **that works** in Postman using the generate code snippets option.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters in this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/api?user=test&password=123
```

are in the query string, not in the body and thus the `content-type` does not apply to them - they are properly encoded to be in a URL.  In Express, you would access these with `req.query`.  You should see a value for `req.query.user` and `req.query.password` in your Exprss request handler.

Note, it is not recommended that you send user credentials in a URL like this because URLs are often present in log files at your ISP, at the recipient server, in proxies, in your browser history, etc...  User credentials like this should be sent in POST request over https where the credentials would go encoded in the body (where it won't be logged or saved by intermediaries).

The fetch error is accurate.  GET requests do not have a body sent with them.  That would be for POST or PUT requests.  A GET request is a "get" request for a resource that you specify only with a URL.

Comment: That makes sense and I got it working, thanks a ton. Is Postman just ignoring that error and sending a body anyway? That's totally what messed me up. And I just used user and password as an example, I'm actually sending different data but it was probably a bad example since, as you said, credentials should go in a POST request.

Comment: @Grav - We'd have to see a network trace of the actual request to see what Postman was doing, but in any case, that's not how you would use a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing request body with a query string.

Your second request (you don't need a Content-Type for it)

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3000/api?user=test&password=123");
```

would be handled by the following Express function:

```js
app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query); // Note that query, not body is used.
    res.sendStatus(200);
    return;
});
```

You can access fields from the query object as `req.query.user` && `req.query.password`.

As for having a request body in a `GET` request: while [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) doesn't explicitly fordbid it, it requires server to not change response based on the contents of the body, i.e. the body in `GET` has no meaning in the standard, so JS HTTP APIs (both `fetch` & `XmlHttpRequest`) deny it.

Answer (score 0):

firstly if you are trying to get some data from your API or others API you should do GET request in order to get your desired data from server for example, if you want to get a specific things like a user or something else you can pass your data in GET request URL using query string or route params.
secondly, if you want to authenticate and send your credentials to the server its not recommended to use GET request as i said earlier GET request simply is for fetching some data from server, so if you want to send your credential or anything else you are better off using POST request to send data to the server and you can't do POST request in the browser, so you have to use something like postman or insomnia in order to send your POST request to the server. i hope it could help you to solve your issue.